# Getting CORS error in browser console on hitting Spartacus storefront URL from the cloud

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

When I am hitting spartacus storefront from my cloud, I am getting the below error:-
Access to XMLHttpRequest at'https://electronics.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/rest/v2/electronics/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=homepage&lang=en&curr=USD' from origin 'https://jsapps.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
electronics.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/rest/v2/electronics/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=homepage&lang=en&curr=USD:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Access to XMLHttpRequest at'https://electronics.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/rest/v2/electronics/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=/not-found&lang=en&curr=USD' from origin 'https://jsapps.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
GET https://electronics.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/rest/v2/electronics/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=/not-found&lang=en&curr=USD net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the storefront, but I faced the same issue in my project in reactJS. I solved it adding a prefix URL

```
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
cosnt url = 'Your URL'
axios.get(proxyurl + url)
```

You need to adapt the same to your project. The basics remain the same I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to adjust your CORS setup in your SAP Commerce Cloud configuration. See https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud/#configuring-cors

Comment: I already added all these properties  corsfilter.ycommercewebservices.allowedOrigins=http://localhost:4200 https://localhost:4200
corsfilter.ycommercewebservices.allowedMethods=GET HEAD OPTIONS PATCH PUT POST DELETE
corsfilter.ycommercewebservices.allowedHeaders=origin content-type accept authorization cache-control if-none-match

Comment: Your javascript is not running on localhost:4200 now is it?  So you need to change the allowedOrigins to match where it is actually running from, which in your case appears to be `https://jsapps.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com`

Comment: I have changed it accordingly under the backoffice aspect session in manifest.json file. Still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a CORS issue, I always recommend to first load the request in a blank browser window. This browser will not require CORS, and if the response is successful, you know you need to fix CORS. Often, however, it is *not* a CORS issue, and this helps you to understands what's going on.

When I load the [request](https://electronics.cmlp705ek-wiprolimi1-d1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/rest/v2/electronics/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=homepage&lang=en&curr=USD) in a separate browser, it becomes clear that we have another issue at hand. The response is showing web application response (the accelerator), instead of an API response. There seem to be a misconfiguration of the so-called `baseUrl` of OCC.

This is likely happening in the ccv2 setup. I assume its in your manifest.xml. You need to check the setup with the following in mind:

- Spartacus requires a `baseUrl` to build all requests to OCC. You can [read up on this in our docs](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/configuring-base-url/).
- The `baseUrl` can be statically configured in Spartacus, but you can also inject it in ccv2, using the `occ-backend-base-url` meta tag. I assume this is what you did, and that's recommended.
- CCv2 deploys various so-called `aspects`. Each aspect can contain one or multiple applications of the platform. You can configure the aspects in the manifest.
- CCv2 will inject the API aspect of your setup in the `occ-backend-base-url` meta tag.

My assumption is that there's a misconfiguration with the API aspect. It might not be available, or might not have the OCC application.

Comment: Only realised just now that this is an older post. I guess it comes too late. Well, I hope it  might help others ;)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

If you face the issue with 2005 Commerce Cloud version. Please try by replacing the **rest** with **occ** in app.module.ts file ,as in version 2005 ycommercewebservices extension is replaced with commercewebservices extesnion which has webroot as /occ where as  the latter has webroot /rest.